# Convert new histogram made by histogram equalization into image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've written histogram equalization code in python, now I have the new histogram of the image. But how do I convert it to an image?

```
im=[9,8,11,4,10,15,4,3] # ex of pixel value of image
summ= sum(im)
pk = []

for i in im:
    pk.append(i/summ)

cdf = []      
for i in range(len(pk)):
    if(i!=0):
        pk[i] = pk[i-1] + pk[i]
    cdf.append(pk[i])

sk=[]
for i in cdf:
    sk.append(i * (len(im) - 1))

hist_x=[]
for i in sk:
    hist_x.append(round(i))

hist_x = np.array(hist_x)
hist_y = np.array(im)
plt.plot(hist_x, hist_y)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you mean by "histogram equalization" and show us the code?

Comment: Equalization is meant to generate a lookup table, not a new histogram (which is flat and of no use).

Comment: please review the [tour] and [ask]. your question is lacking in a few regards, such as there is no [mre]

Comment: @Herman I've had added the code

Comment: sorry about the delay guys

Comment: @selin It doesn't quite run yet, it misses the variables `np` and `plt`

Comment: But I'm thinking the solution will be making a nice graph with `matplotlib`